# Tsiolkovsky rocket equation derivation

Tags: integration

I was attempting to derive the Tsiolkovsky Rocket Equation from momentum conservation. I wrote:

$(M-dM)*V2-MV1=dM*V_{e}$

Continuing:

$MdV-dM*V2=dM*V_{e}$

Thus:

$MdV=dM*(V_{e}+V2)$

And so:

$dV/(V_{e}+V2)=dM/M(t)$

and now saying that V2=V(t+dt) I then am confused about how to integrate... What have I botched here?

I've seen people set $M_{0}$ and $M_{1}$ to define the M's and I know how to do it that way but I want to know what's wrong with my above method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a reference frame issue.  We simply need to realize that the velocity, say $u$, of $dM$ in the reference frame of the rocket is given by $u=-(V_2+V_e)$.  Then,

$$\begin{align}
MdV=-udM &\implies dV=-u\frac{dM}{M}\\\\
&\implies \bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{V(t)-V(0)=u\log(M(0)/M(t))}
\end{align}$$

Comment: Okay, thank you for your prompt response. So a couple things I'm wondering: What about the left side: (Is it really MdV? considering the fact that M is changing throughout the dV...) and can you do our the algebra...I'm sorry this problem is just getting me!

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.  And yes, it really is in the limiting sense $MdV$.  Remember that a term such as $f(x+\delta x)=f(x)+f'(x)\delta x+O(\delta^2)$ and the term $\delta^2$ is an order of magnitude smaller than $\delta$ which we eventually take to $0$.

Comment: Wait so are you saying that every integral is a first order approximation?

Comment: What really bothers me about the Tsiolkovsky derivation is that $(M_{1}-M_{0})*dV=dM*V_{e}$ on the left side says that $dP=dMdV$ which is not true at all, since: $(M_{1}-M_{0})*(V_{1}-V_{0}) \ne dMdV$

Comment: ^If someone could clear this up that would be awesome! So I think I know how to take integrals with infinitesimal elements, but putting those infinitesimal elements into conservation equations and then integrating is really killing me.

Comment: Well, of course I am not saying that any integral is an approximation djax.  Where did I write anything of the sort?  On the issue of the development, where does one see $dMdV$?  We see $MdV-VdM$.   And moving to the rocket's reference frame, we have $MdV=-udM$.  So, I am still trying to help, but do not quite understand the point at which you are having questions.  I am happy to continue.

Comment: Yes thank you, it's I that's struggling to understand. I'm going to have the think about it more. I think one could make the argument that MdV isn't quite correct because it's an approximation of what really happens... So I don't quite see the right and left side holding. I marked your answer as right. I'm going to keep thinking about it. Thanks